# Validate Visual Work-Flow to ensure at least one field is selected

Tags: visualforce, validation, visual-workflow

I have a Visual Work-Flow that has a 10 checkbox fields on page. I wish to insert validation so that the user cannot get through to the next page without selecting at least one checkbox to True. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you'd need to do is

1. select a multi-select checkbox on your screen
2. add your choices
3. set the required field to true
4. and you're good to go!

EDIT: The exact functionality you require is not built in, but there is a way to do it (although extremely tedious and not very elegant).
Use a decision element right after the screen with the checkboxes. Add the condition you require, in your case 10 OR conditions.
 If it does not meet your criteria, bring them back to the same screen or an identical screen with a label on top specifying that at least one checkbox needs to be selected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is not an option for my current situation. I have 10 individual checkbox fields on the Flow that map into checkbox fields on the Case object.

Using multi-select checkboxes will not work in my situation because: 1. I cannot get choice fields on Flow to map to Picklist 2. I need to put text in between every two checkbox fields which is not possible with multi-select (I cannot use several multi-select because i just need 1 of 10 selected.)

Is there any other of using validation on traditional checkbox fields on the Flow to say that at least one must be selected?

Comment: Edited my reply based on your reqirement

Comment: Remember to mark it as the answer if it helped you! :)

Comment: Unfortunately this will not be an option due to the time it will take to amend. Out of interest, could you please tell me which type of record fields (if any) do actually map with 'multi-select checkbox' fields in the Flow?

Comment: I don't understand..It shouldn't take you more than 10 minutes to make this change if you've got the screen set up.

Comment: To answer your question, you'll have to select the value of the multi-select field on any subsequent elements. This returns all the options selected separated by a semi-colon